# post_parent and post__in don't work together

Tags: wordpress

i'm trying to get this code to work but it seems that the post__in condition is not being taken into account by the query:

```
$currentPostID = get_the_ID();

$parentPostID = wp_get_post_parent_id($currentPostID);
    
    
if ($parentPostID) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_parent' => $parentPostID,
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post__not_in' => array($currentPostID),
        'post__in' => $parentPostID,
        
    );

    $query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Is there a way to make it work?

I saw that it can be done by merging two queries but I'm looking for a way to do it in a single query to make them as fast as possible

Comment: `post_parent` selects posts that have the given post ID as parent. You are providing the same ID for `post_parent` and `post__in` here, meaning you are looking for a post, that is _its own_ "parent" - makes no sense.

Comment: _"Is there a way to make it work?"_ - if we could get a proper explanation, of what "it" is actually supposed to be ... because right now, I can't even tell what exactly it is you even want to achieve here.

Comment: 'post' post type does not have a 'post_parent' attribute. It's used with hierarchical post types like 'page'. So your query is not functioning as expected because of these issues.

Answer (score 1):

It expects an array of post IDs, but you are passing a single post ID. Try this:

```
$currentPostID = get_the_ID();

$parentPostID = wp_get_post_parent_id($currentPostID);
    
    
if ($parentPostID) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_parent' => $parentPostID,
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post__not_in' => array($currentPostID),
        'post__in' => array($parentPostID),
        
    );

    $query = new WP_Query($args);
}
```

Comment: already tried this, with this code return 0 result.